# Using fetch for a POST request to add data to JSON server database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, json-server

Trying to add something new to my fake database using JSON server.

The problem is that when I run the function the input information is not added. However a id in my database is created but no body content.

My code:

```js
// newName + newNumber are values from user input
 const contactObject = {
        name: newName,
        number: newNumber,
        date: new Date().toISOString(),
        id: persons.length + 1,
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(contactObject))

      fetch('http://localhost:3001/phonebook', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(contactObject),
      })
```

The console log from above shows `{"name":"test","number":"12345","date":"2020-10-29T01:50:17.345Z","id":9}`

My JSON database shows

```json
// hardcoded data
 {
      "name": "Mary Poppendieck",
      "number": "39-23-6423122",
      "id": 4
    },
// data from running my create new function
    {
      "id": 5
    }
```

I expected data would include name, number, data, ID. But instead only get an ID.

Not sure what i'm doing here as its my first time doing any CRUD operations.

Comment: perhaps it's your backend code that is doing *something wrong™*

Comment: try setting content type to `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the following to my functionality.

```json
 headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
```

Full code:

```json
fetch('http://localhost:3001/phonebook', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(contactObject),
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
      })
```